# Changing image consumes lot of time

Tags: android, bitmap, imageview

Is there any way that I can increase the speed of setting the image? What I am trying to say is suppose I have some hundreds of images and each of those images can be changed automatically or by pressing forward/rewind buttons. (Think of the media player situation where you can forward or rewind as many files, same I am doing with images and some audio behind).

Now, if I continuously keep pressing RW/FW buttons, the layout appears to be black for some time or asks for force close or wait of the application.

Any one know how to increase this speed of reading the bitmap and setting it to the imageview?

Here is a part of my code,

```
  private void playAudio() {
    msg = new Message();
    msg.obj = (filepath);
    imageHandler.sendMessage(msg);
 } 

 private Handler imageHandler = new Handler() {
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {

        try {
            path = (String) msg.obj;
            imagePath = RaconTours.PATH + path;
            imagenamearray = imagePath.split("/");
            currentImagename = imagenamearray[8];
            i++;
            if (!imagePath.equalsIgnoreCase(staticpath)) {
                isSeekBarChangedManually = false;
                staticpath = imagePath;
                Bitmap snoop = readBitmap(Uri.fromFile(new File(filepath)));
                image.setImageBitmap(snoop);
                image.setMaxZoom(4f);
           } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
          }
     }
};
```

Hope you get some idea with this code, this is just a small piece of the big cake.

I am not getting the method to solve this. I tried disabling the button also until some action is being performed but that is also of no use.

Any help, cheers

Answer (score 0):

I think the only way to make this process "faster" is to load and cache the bitmaps in a buffer before you actually need them. When you need a bitmap, you check this forward-cache to see if it's already loaded. If it is, then it means it's already in memory -> you just need to set it for the proper ImageView (or whatever you use). If not, then you load it from the disk.

Of course, you need to know that which bitmaps you'll need most likely in the near future for this to work.

You can't really make disk I/O work any faster you see.

Comment: Zsombor, I din't understand fully what you said. I will look on this once